# JavaScript newbie and trying to open a text file as HTML in Google Chrome. HOW?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Currently reading ***Beginning JavaScript*** and it's asking me to open up a text file with HTML code that I've saved to my HD in my browser. This might be easier in other browsers, but I'm using Google Chrome.

I've searched all over Google and the only answers i can find are how to make code appear as text, but I'm trying to the opposite. Make text appear as what the code is commanding.

EDIT: 5/12/16 1:53AM Eastern time

All of your comments were very helpful! Thanks for the swift responses.    they solved my issue. I literally just wanted to view the code text as HTML in my browser and yes I am also typing into Notepad for now. I'll work on my terminology.

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Slightly confused here. Do you have a .txt file , or is it asking you to open a text file, write HTML, save it as .html and then open it?

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the file to a HTML file.

If you have a text editor like Sublime Text, Notepad++ or (my favorite) Programmers Notepad, open your file in the text editor and save it as a .html file. All you need to do is change the file extension (the bit at the end) from .txt to .html

If you don't have a text editor, notepad will work (in Windows, not sure about mac or linux).

Then just double click the file and it should open in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you are studying some javascript code and you want to test the .txt snippets and run it in html or you want to just use the pre-made .txt file as html code.

If its **case one**

Create a new HTML file using notepad or equivalent software, create a "<script>" element and embed your snippet there

```
<script> Your code here (if its only javascript code)</script>
```

and save it, now drag and drop the file in browser.

If its **case 2**

Open the .txt file in notepad or equivalent go to save as, save it with .html extension or you can even just right click on it and change .txt to .html -> now drag and drop the file in chrome.